# SharePoint Online: Open in client app or web browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I know that I can configure the site Collection or document library so that documents are either opened in the client (Word, Excel, etc) or browser when the user clicks the document link.

However, I would like to provide the user a way to chose which way the document is opened. Preferably, each document in the document library should have two links, one that opens the document in the browser and one that opens the document in the client app.

Any ideas on how/if this can be accomplished? If this needs customizing the document library webpart, please provide details :-)

Thanks,
Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is already developed. :)

[image: ellipse options]

Comment: You can also right-click on the 3 dots to bring up the same menu a little quicker.